# Sizing a `Labeled` figure

Tags: plotting, charts, size, labeled

I am trying to control the overall width of a `Labeled` bar chart. However, it seems whether I put `ImageSize->225` as an option of `BarChart` or as an option of `Labeled`, the size `225` is actually the size of the graphics object produced by `BarChart` and the labels will be outside this size (as shown in the figure below). When I `Export` the figure `pic` in pdf format, the width will exceed `225` due to the labels. How can I control the overall width of `pic` to be exactly `225`? Besides, is there a way to shorten the "tick marks" of `BarChart` below the horizontal axis?

[image]

Here is the code to produce the figure:

```
n = Range[10];
dat1 = 1/n^2;
dat2 = 0.9 dat1;
dat = {dat1, dat2};
sty = {Orange, Black};

SetOptions[BarChart, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 8}, 
  AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.5], LabelStyle -> Black];
SetOptions[Labeled, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 8}];

pic = Labeled[
  BarChart[Transpose@dat, ChartStyle -> {Orange, Black}, 
   BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[n, Above, Style[#, FontSize -> 8] &], None},
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 225], {"Horizontal Axis", 
   "Vertical Axis"}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not include the labels using [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel)? Including the option in the [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart) function causes the funky ticks to disappear, so you can do this afterwards using [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show):

```
g = Show[
    BarChart[
        Transpose@dat,
        ChartStyle->{Orange,Black},
        BarSpacing->{0,1},
        ChartLabels->{Placed[n,Above,Style[#,FontSize->8]&],None},
        AspectRatio->1/2,
        ImageSize->225
    ],
    Frame->{{True,False},{True, False}},
    FrameTicks->{{Automatic,None},{None,None}},
    FrameLabel->{{"Vertical Axis",None},{"Horizontal Axis",None}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> Opacity[1],
    FrameStyle -> {{None, None}, {Directive[FontOpacity -> 1, Opacity[0]], None}},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.02]}, {Scaled[.02], Scaled[.05]}}
]
```

[image]

Check that the size is correct:

```
Rasterize[g, "BoundingBox"]
```

> {225, 128, 67}

Comment: Thanks, @Carl Woll. I have tried `FrameLabel`, and yeah it caused the ticks to disappear for the horizontal axis. But after `Show`, it looks wired to have those bars floating slightly above the axis.

Comment: @nanjun See update. I used Opacity[0] to make the horizontal frame invisible, and then added an Opacity[1] to make sure the vertical ticks appear, and adjusted the plot range padding so that there is no gap between the 0 tick on the vertical axis and the bar chart horizontal line.

Comment: Thank you again, @Carl Woll. Is it also possible to make those downward "tick marks" along the horizontal line shorter, e.g., half the default length?

Comment: @nanjun I think changing the length of the tick marks warrants its own question. The only method I can think of is to postprocess the graphics, something like `graphic /. Line[{a_, Offset[b_, c_]}] :> Line[{a, Offset[b/2, c]}]`

Comment: Thank you, Carl. I just asked a separate question.